# htaccess Redirect Domain to Subdirectory

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

A client wants to redirect a domain (oldsite.com) to a new domain & subdirectory (newsite.com/subdirectory). I have this code setup and it works for for oldsite.com, but when I test oldsite.com/subdomain I get a 404 at newsite.com.

```
Redirect 301 / http://www.newsite.com/subdomain/
```

Is there a way to handle any subdomain requests at oldsite.com so they all redirect to newsite.com/subdirectory? Maybe a wildcard?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this in the `.htaccess` of the web root of the old site:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^subdomain/(.*) http://newsite.com/subdirectory/$1 [B,NE,R,L]
```

Comment: Thanks for this. However it appears to still behave the same as the code I was using, in that I get a 404 on the new site when I add a subdomain (e.g. oldsite.com/subdomain). I confirmed that mod_rewrite is loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} oldsite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule (.*) http://newsite.com/subdirectory/$1 [QSA,L]
```